# How do you change the default indent and set your own in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I don't like how the default when you open a new Google Doc is no first line indent.

Is there a way to customize the default?

Comment: you will need a custom script with onOpen trigger but still this will run only on those docs that have this script, so unless you end up copying such "template doc" everytime you need new doc, then it cant be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the styles how you wish.

Now Format -> Paragraph Styles -> Options -> Save as my default styles

[image: save styles.]